# How can i prove that $k!$ is independent of the choice of $K$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Lets start with a definition.
We define $k!$ as $$k!=\operatorname{card}\{f: f\text{ permutation  of }K\}$$ with $K$ a set with cardinal number $k$. How can we prove that $k!$ is independent for the choice of $K$?

Comment: What? It's not independent of $K$.  If $|K|\ne k$ than $car\{permutation \ of \ K\} \ne k!$.  Do mean if $K = \{6$ ducks $\}$ and $J=\{6$ trucks$\}$ how do we know if the number of permutations of $6$ ducks is the same as the number of permutations of $6$ trucks is the same number of permutations of any other set with six ellements.  Well, if $J$ and $K$ have the same cardinality we can associate each duck with a specific truck.  Every permutation we do with ducks, we can do an equivalent permutation with the associated trucks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: If $K_1$ and $K_2$ are two sets of cardinality $k$, there is a bijection $h:K_1\to K_2$. Use $h$ to construct a bijection between the set of permutations on $K_1$ and the set of permutations on $K_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively you are asking if we have set of $k$ things and another set of $k$ different things, then the numbers of ways to arrange the first set of things should be the same number of ways to arrange the second set of things.  For example, the number of ways to arrange $6$ ducks, should be the same as the number of ways to arrange to arrange $6$ trucks.

This should be intuitively obvious.  All that matters is how many things you have and whether the things are ducks, truck, computer chips, or potato chips how you combine them has nothing to do with *what* they are and only how many they are.

But... this is mathematics and nothing can be justified by "its intuitively obvious".  After all, we actually have a formal definition as to what it means to say "there are six ducks" or "there are six trucks".  We sneak it in sideways because to question the "what does it mean to count there are six trucks" is so... "obvious"... that a student would think it strange to question it.  But $|\{Donald, Daffy, Baby Huey, Howard, Ping, Jemima Puddle-duck\}| = 6$ means that there is a bijection $f:\mathbb J_6 \to \{Donald, Daffy, Baby Huey, Howard, Ping, Jemima Puddle-duck\}$ via $f(1) = Donald; f(2)=Daffy; f(3)=Baby Huey; f(4)=Howard; f(5)=Ping; f(6)=Jemima Puddle-duck$.  It might seem strange, but we have *literally* just *defined* what it means to "Count the number of ducks".

Okay... to answer your question 3 ways with varying degrees of intuition vs. formality.

1) Why is the number of ways to arrange a set of six ducks the same as the number of ways to arrange a set of six trucks.  Well, give each of the trucks the same name as one of the ducks.  So any way you can arrange the six ducks, you can do the same arrangement with the trucks with the same names.

2) More practical.  If you have $6$ things you will have $6$ choices of the first things.  It doesn't matter what the things actually are; all that matters is that there are $6$ of them.  So if you have a set of $6$ ducks you will have $6$ choices and if you have a set of $6$ trucks you still have the same number of choices.

The next step we have $5$ choices of the remaining $5$ items.  But every step of the way, we will have the same number of choices because it is the number of items that matter, not what the items are.

So in the end the total number of permutations are the same.

3)  $|K| = |J|$ means there is a bijection $\phi:K \to J$ so that for every $w\in K$ there is exactly $1$ $v_w\in J$ so that $\phi(w)=v_w$ and for ever $v\in J$ there is exactly $1$ $w_v\in K$ so that $\phi^{-1}(v) = w_v$ (or in other words so that $\phi(w_v) = v$).

Formally a permutation on $K$ is a bijective mapping $\pi: K\to K$.

Now Let $S_K = \{$ permutations on $K\}=\{\pi| \pi: K \to K$ is a bijection$\}$ and let $S_J= \{$ permutations on $J\}=\{\pi| \pi: J \to J$ is a bijection$\}$

Now we have the bijection $\phi: K \to J$.

Consider this function:

$\Phi: S_K \to S_J$ via for any $\pi: K\to K; \pi \in S_K$ then $\Phi(\pi)$ is the function $\Phi(\pi): J\to J$ where for any $v\in J$ then $\Phi(\pi)(v) = \phi(\pi(\phi^{-1}(v)))$.

That is to say:  If $\pi$ is a permutation that maps $w\in K$ to $\omega \in K$, then $\Phi(\pi)$ is a permutation that maps $\phi(w)\in J$ to $\phi(\omega)\in J$.

I'll leave it as an exercise to prove this is a well defined bijection that maps permutations to permutations.  (It's tedious but trivial... everything just maps where it should).

Notice that this is nothing more or less than the first argument.  If we have give the ducks the same names as trucks, a permutation that maps $Donald Duck$ to $Daffy Duck$ will correspond with a permutation that maps $DonaldTruck$ to $Daffy Truck$.